# Unable to access .xlsx file from folder created during execution of script [Python]

Tags: python-2.7

I want to access(print) a xlsx file from the folder which is created during execution of the script.
But, I am not sure how to print it. Can anyone help ??

Thanks :)

```
In main.py script, I asked user to input folder name : 
output_folder = raw_input('Enter the output folder name: ') 

Then in another script, 

import main 
import pandas as pd
import os

output_rm_folder = os.path.join(dir, 'ODEs', main.output_folder) 
output_xls = pd.read_excel('ODEs', main.output_folder, 'name.xlsx') (I know this is not correct)
```

Now I want to access the xls file from this new generated folder.

Comment: you might want to be a bit more verbose and actually show what you tried. This is not a general-purpose free-of-charge script-writing site.

Comment: @planetmaker I have tried to explain, please let me know if you can help me out here